# Submit Form on Enter press - Textfield value is Null

Tags: java, ajax, events, form-submit, wicket-1.5

In my login page I am trying to bind enter key press event with password textfield. I have managed to fire the event listener. But the problem I am facing is the value of the textfield username is returning null, but the password field's value is not null. The code is given below:

```
public class LoginForm extends Form<Void> {
    private transient final ValueMap properties = new ValueMap();

    public LoginForm(final String formId) {
        super(formId);

        final TextField<String> username = new TextField<String>("username", new PropertyModel<String>(getProperties(), "username"));
        add(username);

        final TextField<String> password = new TextField<String>("password", new PropertyModel<String>(getProperties(), "password"));
        add(password);

        password.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeypress") {

            @Override
            protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
                Component component = getComponent();
                if (component.isEnabled() && component.isEnableAllowed()) {
                    CharSequence handler = generateCallbackScript(new AppendingStringBuffer("wicketAjaxPost('").append(getCallbackUrl()).append("', wicketSerialize(Wicket.$('" + getComponent().getMarkupId() + "'))"));
                    String event = "if (event.keyCode == 13) {" + handler.toString() + "};";
                    tag.put("onkeypress", event);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {                 
                System.out.println(getUsername());
                System.out.println(getPassword());
            }
        });
    }

    public ValueMap getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    private String getPassword() {
        return getProperties().getString("username");
    }

    private String getUsername() {
        return getProperties().getString("password");
    }
}
```

The `system.out` is printing

```
null
password
```

I also tried to use `username.getDefaultModelObject()` but that is also returns null.

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to submit your LoginForm via Javascript. This would trigger the usual Wicket form processing and store the values in the models. You should be able to submit a form via:

```
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
```

But, I have not tested it.